# Проблемы с чтением кода

Tags: c++, c

Как прочитать(понять) этот код?

```
   famicom->intrefaces.load_rom = sfc_load_default_rom;
```

Comment: Есть указатель `famicom`, который адресует структуру в которой есть подструктура с именем `interfaces`, в которой есть поле `load_rom`. Этому полю (в конечном итоге адресуемому указателем) присваивается новое значение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
famicom->intrefaces.load_rom = sfc_load_default_rom;
```

1. `;` => это statement
2. `=` => присваивание lhs значения rhs
3. `->` => оператор доступа к члену объекта, на который указывает указатель
4. `.` => оператор доступа к члену объекта без указателей

Так что, если ничего не перегружено/задефайнено и т.п., получаем:

> Присваивание значения `sfc_load_default_rom` члену `load_rom` объекта
> `intrefaces`, который является членом `*famicom`

Comment: Та за шо минус?

Comment: Наверное кто-то посчитал столь подробный и формальный рассказ издевательством.